# ¿Se puede detener un bucle for, cuando detecte una condición?

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular5, bucle-for, bucles

Hola mi problema es que recorro todos los usuarios que tengo en mi api rest, y quiero que una vez esté haciendo el recorrido si detecta que hay uno igual me lance un mensaje de que ese usuario ya existe y que pare de seguir con el bucle for. Y si no existe ese usuario que lo termine de ejecutar ese bucle for y que al final inserte ese usuario.

Mi cuestión es si es posible hacer lo que he comentado anteriormente.
Y si se pudiera me podrían decir como sería para detener ese bucle.
Estoy usando Ionic 3 , Angular 5 y Slim como api-rest de back-end por si tuviera relevancia la función según lo que use.

Gracias de antemano.

```js
guardarNicknameUsuario() {
  this.userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
        this.users = data;
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.users[i].nickname);

          if (this.users[i].nickname === this.nicknameUsuario.value.nickname) {
            // alert("Este usuario existe ya, porfavor introduce otro nickname");
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Este usuario ya existe',
              subTitle: 'Introduzca otro nickname',
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alert.present();
          } else {
            // alert("por que entras");
            this.userService.postDatos(this.nicknameUsuario.value.nickname);
            console.log(this.nicknameUsuario.value.nickname);
            window.localStorage['nickUsuarioAplicacion'] = this.nicknameUsuario.value.nickname;
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
          }
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    )

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí se puede detener un bucle for, usa `break`

Referencia

- [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/break)

Answer (score 0):

Toda estructura repetitiva puede ser detenida con la palabr reservada **break**, que significa exactamente eso, interrumpir una acción.